# How to define a weighted loss function in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a training dataset of train_data and train_labels which is train_data_node and train_labels_node in the graph of tensorflow.
As you know, I can use the loss function of tensorflow as bellows:

```
logits = model(train_data_node)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    logits,train_labels_node))
```

However, this loss function processes all the training data equally.
But in our situation, we want to process the data discriminately.
For example, we have a csv file corresponding to the training data to indicate the train data is original or augmented.
Then we want to define a custom loss function which makes the loss of original data play more important role and the loss of augmented data play less important role, such as:

```
loss_no_aug = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(noAugLogits, noAugLabels))
loss_aug = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(augLogits, augLabels))
loss = loss_no_aug * PENALTY_COEFFICIENT + loss_aug
```

I have defined a loss function as bellow, but it didn't work:

```
def calLoss(logits, labels, augs):
  noAugLogits = []
  noAugLabels = []
  augLogits = []
  augLabels = []
  tf.get_collection()
  for i in range(augs.shape[0]):
    if augs[i] == 1:
      noAugLogits.append(logits[i])
      noAugLabels.append(labels[i])
    else:
      augLogits.append(logits[i])
      augLabels.append(labels[i])
  noAugLogits = tf.convert_to_tensor(noAugLogits)
  noAugLabels = tf.convert_to_tensor(noAugLabels)
  augLogits = tf.convert_to_tensor(augLogits)
  augLabels = tf.convert_to_tensor(augLabels)
  return tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
      noAugLogits, noAugLabels)) * PENALTY_COEFFICIENT + \
      tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(augLogits, augLabels))
```

I think we should write the loss function using tensor operations, however, I am not familiar with them. So could anyone give me some advice on how to define the loss function.

Thank you for your kind answers or suggestions.

Comment: I have found some functions in tensorflow to process tensors, such as, tf.cond(), tf.boolen_mask and tf.gather(). But I do not know how to use them. And in our situation, the key question is how to slice the data and label tensors according to the augs tensor which is composed of 0 or 1 corresponding to augmentation and non-augmentation. So could anybody give me a suggestion? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally solved the problem by myself using the function tf.boolen_mask() of tensorflow. The defined custom weighted loss function is as bellows:

```
def calLoss(logits, labels, augs):
  augSum = tf.reduce_sum(augs)
  pred = tf.less(augSum, BATCH_SIZE)

  def noaug(logits, labels, augs):
    augs = tf.cast(augs, tf.bool)
    noaugs = tf.logical_not(augs)
    noAugLogits = tf.boolean_mask(logits, noaugs)
    noAugLabels = tf.boolean_mask(labels, noaugs)
    augLogits = tf.boolean_mask(logits, augs)
    augLabels = tf.boolean_mask(labels, augs)
    noaugLoss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(noAugLogits, noAugLabels))
    augLoss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(augLogits, augLabels))
    return noaugLoss * PENALTY_COEFFICIENT + augLoss

  def aug(logits, labels):
    return tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels))

  return tf.cond(pred, lambda: noaug(logits, labels, augs), lambda: aug(logits, labels))
```

As you can see, I use a numpy array variable, augs, using 1 and 0 in corresponding positions to indicate whether a sample in a batch of samples is augmented or non-augmented. Then I convert the variable to a bool tensor and use it as the bool mask of tf.boolen_mask() to fetch the augmented and non-augmented samples and calculate the loss respectively.

Comment: Found it very useful! Thanks for sharing